# Jquery setting value of a droplist

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Today one of my customers has reported that the list values they have set are no longer being seen as set ie they appear with a default value of none (my first value in the list).

i am setting the value in the following way but all of a sudden on the live and test systems this no longer works when it has been working for years! Has something changed recently in Jquery that would change this? I am using this url to reference jquery. Anyone else seeing this issue?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

$('#mylist').val('value');
```

Comment: You need to enclose your jquery code within a seperate script tag. <script> $('#mylist').val('value'); </script> provided that your html is loading before the script in the code. If not, then you need to enclose the jquery code within document.ready along with the script tag,

Comment: Sorry yes it is i have just provided an extract of my code. This line is just one of many and when i debug the function this line is from the line is hit but the value of the droplist isnt changed. This used to work and now fails for all droplists and i dont understand why

Comment: As far as I know this works. I imagine it is a syntax error. Can you provide more code? Or see answer below for possible fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$('#mylist').val('value');
```

Try:

```
$('#mylist').val(value);
```

If `value` is the name of a variable, do not use quotes or you will be telling jQuery to use exactly those letters as a string.

---

Also, it is not best practice to use this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

because the jQuery code changes regularly, and sometimes they will remove (or deprecate) functions you may be using, or change how things are done. When you use `jquery-latest` you are getting whatever is the latest, bleeding-edge, stable release of jQuery, with all changes.

It is better to use a specific version of jQuery, such as these alternate CDN choices:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

or

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

---

Idea: at the bottom of your HTML code, add something like this *to manually set the select value to one you specify. Just to ensure you can get that functionality working, double-check spelling etc:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        //Test: Delay 15 secs, then manually set value of drop-down
        $('#incInitialContact').val('a-valid-value');
    },15000);
});
```

*Note: replace `a valid value` with a valid value for your select*

Comment: this is the actual line function (incident) {                       $('#incInitialContact').val(incident.initialContact);} where incident is returned from a call to a .ashx service when i check the value of inicdent.initialContact at this line the value is correct but as i said the value of incInitialContact does not show this value - all of a sudden this affects every list value in the system not just this one

Comment: Can you `console.log(incident.initialContact)` or `alert(incident.initialContact)` and see if the value is what you were expecting?

Comment: yes it shows the correct value so the returned value is correct

Comment: Review `Ryan Dantzler` answer (+1 since we are discussing it). Does your dropdown have a `value=` parameter that matches exactly that text, capitalization included? *Is the capitalization/spelling of the `<select>` tag's ID also exactly correct?*

Comment: yes the value was originally taken from the list and written to a database so it is definately the same value

Comment: taking the comments on board over best practice i agree my use fo <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> is in hindsight not good. I have done a change to one of the above but now get other issues so will come back to that at a later date once i undertand this issue thanks for your input on this point

Comment: I have solved the issue, a different function is being called when the screen is displayed which is resetting the list fields - apologies for wasting anyones time and many thanks for providing the help and assistance. I'm not sure how to close this as complete?

Comment: You are very welcome. Choosing a "most correct" (best) answer closed the question as complete, so thanks for doing that. Glad you solved the pesky issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

To select Value 1:

```
<div class="myList">
  <select>
    <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="val3">Value 3</option>
  </select>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mylist').val('val1');
});
</script>
```